# dot source the files from the script directory in both Powershell console and ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have the following script in directory `c:\scripts\`.

```
# . c:\scripts\anotherScript.ps1
function GetScriptRoot { Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path }
. "$(GetScriptroot)\anotherScript.ps1"
```

However, it raises an error in ISE. Is it a way which works in both console and ISE? I am trying not to use the full absolute path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path property is only available in a running script.

To detect whether your are running in the ISE or not you can check for the `$psise` variable:

```
if ($psise) {
    "Running in the ISE"
} else {
    "Not running in the ISE"
}
```

Or look at the `$host.Name` property:

```
PS C:\Users\andy> $host
Name             : Windows PowerShell ISE Host

PS C:\Users\andy> $host
Name             : ConsoleHost
```

Comment: Ok, maybe I had to use full path in ISE. How to detect the script is running in ISE/Console?